# Strict comparison not producing expected result in production environment but works well on local server

Tags: javascript, mysql, vue.js, switch-statement, laravel-5.5

I am currently using the strict **===** comparison in a javascript, The comparison produces expected result as required on my machine but when deployed to server it doesn't, it behaves differently.

**Script**

```
computed: {
            type: function(){
                switch(this.job.type)
                {
                    case 1:
                        return 'Request Quote';
                    case 2:
                        return 'Negotiate';
                    case 3:
                        return 'Fixed';
                    default:
                        return 'matched none';
                }
            },
}
```

Template

```
<p class="text-primary"><strong>{{type}}</strong></p>
```

Output On Local Server for **job type of 2**

[image: Image showing Negotiate on Local Server]

Output On Production Server for **job type of 2**
[image: Image showing matched none on Production Server]

If i switch code to a loosed comparison If statement, it works well

If statement

```
computed: {
        type: function(){
            if(this.job.type == 1) return 'Request Quote';
            else if(this.job.type == 2) return 'Negotiate';
            else if(this.job.type == 3) return 'Fixed';
            else return 'matched none';
        },
}
```

Result in Production Server
[image]

As you may have noticed I am making use of the VUEJS framework, also the job object is database model fetched with axios. I am also making use of Laravel on the backend.

Could it be an issue with the mysql version?

**Version runnning on Local Machine**
[image: Image showing MYSQL server version on Local Machine]

**Version running in production**
[image]

Comment: Where does the job type come from? Is it a number or a string (if you load json, strings have quotes, numbers don't)

Comment: @Ferrybig, it is coming from an Ajax request I made, and it is a number.

Answer (score 0):

That means that your code/config/etc. in production is creating a string, or a number **object** (rather than primitive), or some other kind of object that when coerced to number coerces to one of your expected values.

Example with a string:

```js
function strict(type) {
    switch(type)
    {
        case 1:
            return 'Request Quote';
        case 2:
            return 'Negotiate';
        case 3:
            return 'Fixed';
        default:
            return 'matched none';
    }
}

function loose(type) {
    if(type == 1) return 'Request Quote';
    else if(type == 2) return 'Negotiate';
    else if(type == 3) return 'Fixed';
    else return 'matched none';
}

var n;
console.log("Number:");
n = 2;
console.log("strict", strict(n));
console.log("loose", loose(n));

console.log("String:");
n = "2";
console.log("strict", strict(n));
console.log("loose", loose(n));
```

Example with a number object:

```js
function strict(type) {
    switch(type)
    {
        case 1:
            return 'Request Quote';
        case 2:
            return 'Negotiate';
        case 3:
            return 'Fixed';
        default:
            return 'matched none';
    }
}

function loose(type) {
    if(type == 1) return 'Request Quote';
    else if(type == 2) return 'Negotiate';
    else if(type == 3) return 'Fixed';
    else return 'matched none';
}

var n;
console.log("Primitive:");
n = 2;
console.log("strict", strict(n));
console.log("loose", loose(n));

console.log("Number object:");
n = new Number(2);
console.log("strict", strict(n));
console.log("loose", loose(n));
```

You'll have to find out what is different in the environment/code/config such that you're ending up with the wrong kind of value for `this.job.type`.

Comment: I get the point you are trying to raise, but i'm yet to see a difference between my server set up and my local server setup, except the mysql version, and when you talk about code/config, could it be my php config you are referring to?

Comment: @JohnDavid: Just about anything, really (unhelpfully).

Answer (score 0):

Check your variable type, I think you're getting a string in production too.

I suggest you using Typescript or Flowtype to avoid those check.